# How to fix syntax error on the 'e' of 'else:' in python - discord.py

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, discord.py

I have no idea why this is happening, I have checked everything and all seems working. Here is the code( the error is about halfway down, I put some arrows next to it in brackets. I'm not sure if it's an indent issue or what. Before this there was an error just above on the "with open('mainbank.json', 'w') as f" bit.

```
@client.command(name='fight_01')
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def fight_goblin(ctx):
  rng1 = random.randint(1,3)
  rng2 = random.randint(1,3)
  if rng1 == int('2'):
    await ctx.channel.send("You searched all around and couldn't find a goblin, try again next time :(")


  else:
    await ctx.channel.send('You encountered a wild goblin!')
    goblin_hp = int('5')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    rng3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):
      user = ctx.author
      users = await get_bank_data()
      await ctx.channel.send('The goblin got the first hit and you lost 1hp')
      users[str(user.id)]['hp'] -= int('1') 
      dmg = users[str(user.id)]['max_damage']
      rng4 = random.randint(0, dmg) 
      rng5 = str(rng4)
      content1 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage'
      goblin_hp2 = goblin_hp - int(rng5)
      with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
       json.dump(users,f)
      users = await get_bank_data()
      if users[str(user.id)]['hp'] <= 0:
        await ctx.channel.send('You died, better luck next time')
      await ctx.channel.send(content1)
      
      
      if goblin_hp2 < int('1'):
        await ctx.channel.send('You killed the goblin')
        users[str(user.id)['bank'] + random.randint(20, 100)  

      
      (HERE IS THE PROBELM >>>>>)else:
        content2 = 'The goblin now has ' + str(goblin_hp2) + ' health left'
        await ctx.channel.send(content2)
        rng3 = random.randint(1, 10)
        if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):
        user = ctx.author
        users = await get_bank_data()
        await ctx.channel.send('The goblin hit you so you lost 1hp')
        users[str(user.id)]['hp'] -= int('1') 
        dmg = users[str(user.id)]['max_damage']
        rng4 = random.randint(0, dmg) 
        rng5 = str(rng4)
        content1 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage'
        goblin_hp2 = goblin_hp - int(rng5)
        with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
          json.dump(users,f)
        users = await get_bank_data()
        if users[str(user.id)]['hp'] <= 0:
          await ctx.channel.send('You died, better luck next time')
        if goblin_hp2 < int('1'):
          await ctx.channel.send('You killed the goblin')
          users[str(user.id)['bank'] += random.randint(20, 100)  
          with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
            json.dump(users,f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is the line before

```
users[str(user.id)['bank'] + random.randint(20, 100)
```

is missing a closing `]`

```
users[str(user.id)]['bank'] + random.randint(20, 100)  
                  ^
```